# test if google cloud storage bucket is existed?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, bucket

I have written this code

```
private void doesBucketExist(String bucketName) {
    try {
        GoogleCredential credential = myUtil.getCredential();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
        HttpTransport transport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Storage.Builder storageBilder = new Storage.Builder(transport, jsonFactory, credential);
        Storage storage = storageBilder.build();
        Objects objects = storage.objects();
        List listObjects = objects.list(bucketName);
        if (listObjects != null && listObjects.getBucket().equalsIgnoreCase(bucketName)) {
            System.out.println("Bucket exist");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Bucket does not exist");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

It is giving `listObjects` even if I pass an un-existed bucket name thus i am getting `Bucket exist`.

I did see [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/issues/1133) but could not use that in my code since `storage` is from different package from what I am using in my program.

How can I make sure if the specified bucket exist or not?

Comment: How do you know the bucket name you pass does not exist? Have you tried to create a bucket with the name in the Dev Console and it is usable? Please note that the bucket namespace is global and publicly visible, so you'll not know if it exist or not until you can or cannot create it :p

Comment: yes, tested with my own name with random number as the name of the bucket and it is still giving the same as if it already existed.

Comment: Can you try to create a bucket with the name (eg, your own name with random numbers) in the Developers Console to see if it still existed or not?

Comment: I am able to create on console, i should not test the existence of the bucket by creating one since i am writing this code for the health of connectivity to the bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Listing or getting the bucket both have problems if you don't have access to the bucket. You may receive a 404 or 403 depending on if the bucket is owned by someone else. Also, there's no guarantee that checking if a bucket exists with one of these methods and then trying to create it later will succeed, since someone may create the bucket in between the two calls.

Instead, the recommended way to check if a bucket exists is to try to create the bucket and look for the error returned. Either it'll succeed with a success HTTP response or it'll fail with a 409 error, indicating the bucket already exists. Note that you should still retry on 5xx error codes.

Comment: I am writing this code to test health check to Google buckets, I have to return respected http response code. And I am using `com.google.api.services.storage`. How can I test in this case?